# Windows Task Scheduling support since Windows XP

Tags: windows, task, scheduler

I have a python script that needs to be run after each reboot.
All I know is that it will be installed on Windows OS, and that the oldest supported version will be XP.

There might be some odd non consumer versions of Windows as well, like POS ready Embedded windows (http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/evaluate/windows-embedded-pos-ready-2009.aspx) or windows server. I'd like to have wide support for a lot of these versions of Windows.

I am developing the script on Windows 7, and I'm using the Task Scheduler GUI right now for testing.

I pull it up with the "control schedtasks" command.

My concern is that older version of Windows won't have this Task Scheduler GUI, or even the command version (schtasks).

Does anybody know how long they've been bundled with the default installations of Windows?

Would it be a good idea to bundle schtasks.exe? Would that even work?

Are there any better alternatives to the solutions I've thought of?

Any insight here would be highly appreciated. I'm a bit lost in the world of Windows.
Thanks!

Comment: Copying a Windows executable from one version of Windows to another almost never works properly.  Besides, it probably wouldn't be legal.  Have you considered making your script a system service?  I believe Python supports doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throw the appropriate call to it into a batch file (make sure python is in your PATH var) and place it in the 'Startup' folder

Windows 7: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Comment: Beautiful. That's just what I need.

Thank you!